# Clearing the entire cache in Apigee

Tags: caching, apigee

When you configure a cache in Edge you give it some key fragments (e.g. request.uri, request.header.Accept, request.header.Accept-Language, etc.).  To clear that key you pass the same key fragments.

If I have 5,000 elements cached, how can I clear the entire cache without generating 5,000 calls to my API with all the possible cache keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the clear all cache entries API call, documented [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api/caches). If you don't pass in the prefix query parameter, it should remove all.

Comment: Okay -- so clear via the API, but no way to do it via the InvalidateCache Policy?

Comment: I don't think you can do it via the policy.

Comment: If you are trying to do it from your run-time APIs - that API would then become dependent on Management Server (performance and availability is the concern)

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate cache policy is used to explicitly invalidate the cache entry for the given CacheKey (Where Cachekey is the combination of 'Prefix and KeyFragment'), not for clearing the all entries, associated with the given Cache resource. Please go through the document [here](http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/optimize-performance-using-cache) to understand more about 'Invalidate Cache'.

Answer (score 0):

The cache can also be cleared from UI.

You can login to UI then go to API's tab under that will be "Environment Configuration" Tab

Here you will get the option to clear entire cache.

Answer (score 0):

The following API call will also allow you to delete all your cache entries :

curl -v -u admin 'https://api.enterprise.apigee.com/v1/organizations/{org-name}/environments/{env-name}/caches/{cache-name}/entries?action=clear' -X POST

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this via policies, you can do it using `KeyFragment` and `PurgeChildEntries` tags.

**Reference** - https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/policies/invalidate-cache-policy#PurgeChildEntriesElement